# Gradle write me AAPT errors

Tags: android, gradle

I try to build my android project, but Gradle write me 3 AAPT errors

```
C:\Users\79659\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\42000e1808a60b173199f1b8b856bd5d\jetified-ads-2.5.1.472\res\drawable\apnxt_ads_rating_bar.xml:3: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/background' for external package 'android'.
```

```
C:\Users\79659\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\42000e1808a60b173199f1b8b856bd5d\jetified-ads-2.5.1.472\res\drawable\apnxt_ads_rating_bar.xml:7: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/progress' for external package 'android'.
```

```
C:\Users\79659\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\42000e1808a60b173199f1b8b856bd5d\jetified-ads-2.5.1.472\res\drawable\apnxt_ads_rating_bar.xml:5: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/secondaryProgress' for external package 'android'.
```

These errors refer to this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/apnxt_ads_empty_star" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/apnxt_ads_empty_star" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/apnxt_ads_full_star" />
</layer-list>
```

This code I can't edit. What can I do?

**UPD:** I have found a solution. The problem was in packages from AppNext. Example:

```
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:ads:2.+'
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:banners:2.+'
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:native-ads2:2.+'
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:actions:2.+'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. The problem was in packages from AppNext. Example:

```
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:ads:2.+'
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:banners:2.+'
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:native-ads2:2.+'
implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:actions:2.+'
```